# Twitter authentication/PHP Oauth: user is asked to reallow the application every time he tries to authenticate

Tags: php, openid, twitter

The code itself is pretty basic. I am trying to allow user to connect to Twitter and later to use Twitter as a mean of authentication (afaik, this is called OpenId). However, the problem is that every time when user executes the code he is asked to reallow the application – instead I expect it to return some sort of variable indicating that user is already connected to the app.

```
$oauth          = new OAuth(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$callback_url   = 'http://guubo.com/connect/1';

try
{
    if(empty($_GET['oauth_token']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['hp']['twitter']);
    }

    if(empty($_SESSION['hp']['twitter']['oauth_token_secret']))
    {
        $access_token   = $oauth->getRequestToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', $callback_url);

        //die(var_dump( $access_token ));

        $_SESSION['hp']['twitter']['oauth_token_secret']    = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        header('Location: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $access_token['oauth_token']);

        exit;
    }
    elseif(!empty($_GET['oauth_token']))
    {
        $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['hp']['twitter']['oauth_token_secret']);

        unset($_SESSION['hp']['twitter']);

        $access_token_info  = $oauth->getAccessToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token');

        $db->exec("INSERT INTO `user_tokens` (`user_id`, `network_id`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`) VALUES ({$db->quote($user['id'])}, {$db->quote($network['id'])}, {$db->quote($access_token_info['oauth_token'])}, {$db->quote($access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'])})");

        $response_array = array();

        parse_str($oauth->getLastResponse(), $last_response);

        #die(var_dump( $last_response[''] ));
    }
}
catch(OAuthException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();

    exit;
}
```

Comment: This code shows how you are storing the authentication to a DB. It does not show how you are retrieving it upon return visits.

Comment: And it shouldn't, because I don't know yet who the user is. That is why I want to use Twitter. I expect that since the user is connected to my Twitter app, the next time he will attempt to connect to it, Twitter will simply return Twitter user's UID which I can use to identify user on my system.

Comment: but how can that happen with the above code? You do not use the DB values and you reauthenticate everytime and unset your `$_SESSION` instead of using your stored tokens.

Comment: Ok. This scenario assumes that: user is already in my database and he has already allowed my application. Using `TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET` I call to get `request_token`, which I later used to `authorize` user. Now at this step I expect Twitter NOT to ask user to allow the app again and simply redirect user back and returning some info that will allow me to distinguish the user. There is no `$_SESSION` as user is trying login to the website using Twitter; there is no data from DB as we still don't know who the user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [document](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter) regarding the "Sign in with Twitter" flow, which it looks like you are trying to implement.  The one thing I notice in your code is that you are calling `oauth/authorize` where you should be calling `oauth/authenticate`.  Here's a relevant excerpt:

> The normal [OAuth] flow dictates that
>   applications send request tokens to
>   oauth/authorize in Twitter's
>   implementation of the OAuth
>   Specification. To take advantage of
>   "Sign in with Twitter", applications
>   should send request tokens received in
>   the oauth_token parameter to
>   oauth/authenticate instead.

Comment: That actually worked. I tried `authentication` method as well, though I didn't realize that I need first to get `request_token`. Thank you.